# Java converting to a char from a string into the correct byte 0-255

Tags: java

Good day,

I am transferring Bluetooth info to my Android app. This information comes in the form of a string via the standard bluetooth chat app example.

I am trying to convert the characters in the string into bytes to be used by the app.

when using `(byte)readMessage.charAt(k)` in java the values for bytes are correct up to 127. I have read that chars are 16 bit and bytes are 8 bit. I don't understand how it does not convert correctly even if the "number" in the char is less than 255.

How do I convert the string into the correct bytes in order to receive the 0-255 serial data coming in with the blue-tooth connection.

```
for(int k = EEPROM_start ; k < EEPROM_start + 60 ; k ++)
{                                                                    
  EEPROM[k] = (byte)readMessage.charAt(k);
}
```

Expected results

If I can get the values in bytes (0-255) that would be great or even (-128:127) I will be able to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that your String comes in a simple character set such as ISO-8859-1 where each character is encoded by a single byte. But that is not always the case. There are character sets that store each character as 1 to 4 bytes. UTF-8, UTF-16, UCS-2 etc. If your incoming info could be encoded in ISO-8859-1 charset (i.e. your string holds only Latin letters and punctuation) then in order to convert your String to bytes where each byte would correlate to a char to this:

```
byte[] myBytes = myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

See the method [String.getBytes(Charset charset);](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-) and class [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)

Comment: Hi Michael, this is how the string is created from the bluetooth handler readMessage = new String(response, 0, chatService.bufferIndex); I have tried your suggestion and keep on geeting answer of -17 for any byte that is 128 or greater

Comment: @Vann I assume that response is a byte array - am I correct? It looks like you already lose some info when creating your string. You need to know in which character set the original info comes. It could be that the original info already comes in UTF-8. Try creating your String with  new String(response, 0, chatService.bufferIndex, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); See if that helps. If not, give me a sample of your response and I might be able to help you

Comment: I found some github bug reports for android regarding chars and bytes. The solution given there was to create  an int variable = char_variable & 255 and so far this has worked for me